# startAfter in firebase is not working properly when using on DATE

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to paginate my app on the basis of date/time using startAfter() method of firebase.In docs, it is written that startAfter() method excludes the starting point.but in my case it is working similar to startAt() method i.e both startAfter() and startAt() are working same.

```
createdOn = new Date("2019-04-06T13:59:29.000Z")
queryRef = await queryRef.orderBy("createdOn").startAfter(createdOn);
```

the result should exclude the date createdOn,
but it includes the same.

```
const db=firebaseAdmin.firestore();


const date1=new Date();

    await db
    .collection(COLLECTION_NAME)
    .doc(ID_1)
    .create({
        name:"steve",
      _createdOn:date1
    });

const date2=new Date();

    await db
    .collection(COLLECTION_NAME)
    .doc(ID_2)
    .create({
        name:"bruce",
      _createdOn:date2
    });

const date3=new Date();

    await db
    .collection(COLLECTION_NAME)
    .doc(ID_3)
    .create({
        name:"chris",
      _createdOn:date3
    });





output ::>


    queryRef.orderBy("_createdOn").startAfter(date2);
    ....
    ...
    ..
    .
    //provides result containing 2nd and 3rd user



    queryRef.orderBy("_createdOn").startAt(date2);
    ....
    ...
    ..
    .
    //also provides result containing 2nd and 3rd user
```

Comment: Can you show your data model (database structure and value of the field you query on)